# How to boot back into Windows 8 after deleting its boot path?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I recently booted into Ubuntu 12.04 for the first time and had great difficulty doing it. In the process I may have deleted the boot path back to Windows 8. I'm not sure I just really wanted Ubuntu, but now I feel like since this should be a dual boot. I have the right to get back into Windows 8 if I ever wanted to. When in grub I can select Windows 8 to boot into, but an error screen pops up which says:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD  

  Status: 0xc000000c  

  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do adding/removing entries to grub by using grub-customizer

open your terminal and type these lines one after one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then open your Grub-customizer from Unity dash.

Comment: Ok I just got that but now what because I just found that I already have a boot entry but when I try to boot into windows an error says that "the boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors."

Comment: @LandonLedbetter edit your question with that message or start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this command once you have logged in into Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Example output:

```
Generating grub.cfg …
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sdb1
finished
```

The penultimate line says that Windows is found and will be available during boot.

If when you try to boot into Windows an error screen appears saying:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next." 
 3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance. 

File: \Boot\BCD 
Status: 0xc000000c 
Info: The boot configuration data is missing or contains errors.
```

Try to boot from Windows DVD, then run the command

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C:
```

`C:` drive should reside on active partition.

Then reboot into Ubuntu and run the `sudo update-grub` command again.

Comment: Ok well then I do have a boot entry but when I try to boot into windows an error screen reads: "windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  File: \Boot\BCD                                                      Status: 0xc000000c                                                  Info: The boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors."

Comment: Try to boot from Windows DVD, then run the command `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C:`. Then run the `update-grub` command again.

Comment: Ok well I'm going to have to get a windows DVD and try but as of now I don't have one. But when I do get one and try Ill post back results/problems

Answer (score 0):

grub2's os-prober creates wrong style (BIOS) chain boot entry

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1024383

type of entry from Boot-Repair that should work.

```
menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
```

Type of entry from os-prober that does not work:

```
'Windows ...) (on /dev/sdXY)'
```

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Fixes in newest versions not yet in most systems.
os-prober fix in grub2_2.00-14 and os-prober_1.58 from Debian

Answer (score -1):

You can usually still boot into Windows. Try pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> (or whatever boot options hotkey you have) on startup and selecting windows from there. Not an ideal fix, but better than formatting a live CD.

Comment: -1 the OP is beyond the point selecting the right boto device from the BIOS-boot-menu